# How to use apps on Android via adb tools?

Tags: android, linux, adb, whatsapp

I am using Android 6 Marshmellow.

I need to perform a local backup on Whatsapp without access to the screen. The motherboard has been damaged possibly beyond repair. The net result: Nothing displays on the screen. I have tried Windows 10 programs that display the Android screen in a window on PC but they don't work - possibly because the phone is failing to produce an output in the first place.

One program I used is [this](http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/#comment-31841) but the screenshot that the java app takes is pitch black. Hence my assumption the motherboard is incapable of producing a display at all.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way to execute app-specific commands such as telling Whatsapp to create a local backup via adb tools. So use Whatsapp via the Windows command line, through adb, as you can on Linux.

I cannot interact with the display; touch inputs are not registered. It has a password but the phone is not encrypted. My Windows 10 PC is a trusted PC and the phone has developer tools on.

More info [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187120/how-to-perform-local-backup-in-whatsapp-with-a-broken-screen-adb-available).

Comment: You should consider moving this question to SuperUser. Stack Overflow is specifically for programming related questions.

Comment: How do I do this? I could also move it to android.stackexchange?

Comment: I thought answers might relate to programming and use of Android Developer Tools however it doesn't seem this is a very popular or considered question

Answer (score 0):

If you set that phone up for development and you can use adb commands to install an app (and send other intents), you might be able to try this out: [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/)

You can test this by simply turning on your phone, plug it in via USB cable and then run "adb devices" on your PC. Make sure adb.exe is in your Window's path.

Download the Windows app, install it and run it. Then plug in your phone. If this phone has developer options enabled and has been white-listed for the particular PC you're using, then it should allow the Windows app to install the Vysor Android app and start it. Once that happens, it should be able to connect and you'll see the phone's screen on your PC. Try it out with a working phone first if you like.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your emulator device ID. Run:

```bash
adb devices
```

2. Find the package you want to debug. Run:

```bash
adb shell pm list packages .
```

3. Set the app to debug at startup (note the -w)
4. Start the app in the emulator.
5. Connect Android Studio Debugger.
6. Point to source code and set breakpoints.